# command.parameters.addwithvalue not working

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have experienced a problem when saving a record using parameters the following is my code

```
try
{
    string usd = "USR" + randomnumber(001, 1000).ToString();
    dbconn.poconne.Open();
    string useradd = "insert into users values(@userid,@username,@password,@email,@department,@log)";

    using (NpgsqlCommand cmdadd = new NpgsqlCommand(useradd, dbconn.poconne))
    {
        cmdadd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", usd);
    }
}
catch (Exception er)
{
    MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
}
```

I get this error

> Error 1   'Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection' does not contain a
>   definition for 'AddWithValue' and no extension method 'AddWithValue'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\ICT PGL\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\officeautomation\customercare\customercare\users.cs 34  39  customercare

Any help on solving the error please

Comment: I would recommend avoiding using `AddWithValue` anyway. Instead, call `Add` to create the parameter, specifying the name and type, and then set the `Value` property. But it looks like it really *should* be there. Which version of the library are you using?

Comment: [`AddWithValue` *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Does Postgresql also use the `@` as a parameter name prefix? I know T-SQL (MS SQL Server, Sybase) uses this - but that's not an industry-wide standard. Maybe Postgresql uses something else?

Answer (score 2):

Your query:

```
string useradd = "insert into users (id, name, password, email, department, log) values(:userid,:username,:password,:email,:department,:log)";
```

Your parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("userid", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("username", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = usd;
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = "username";
```

I showed just for two parameters. Add other parameters accordingly.

It is better if you appoint the columns where you are going to insert data.

Comment: thanks Khazratbek it worked perfectly and also learned this new method.Thanks Alot

Comment: @tallman you are welcome! Approve any answer and you question will be solved. So other users also can see the correct one and use that.

Comment: my reputation is very low

Comment: @tallman I thought that reputation is not so valuable to approve the answer))

Comment: @tallman You don't need reputation to approve an answer (the green tick next to it, and you will in fact _get_ reputation in the process).